# Make session expiration redirect back to login?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

When user logs in and is authenticated, I use `Auth::user()->username;` to show username of user on dashboard. However, for some reason when session expires the class `Auth` doesn't seem to work and dashboard page throws error as `trying to get property of non-object` for `Auth::user()->username;`. How can I redirect the user back to the login page when he clicks any link or refreshes the page after the session has expired?

I tried the Authenticate.php  middleware but it always redirects back to login page,whatever you put the credentials either correct or incorrect.However,when I don't use this middleware it logins the user.Am I missing something?

Route.php

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/*
Actions Handled By Resource Controller

Verb        Path                    Action      Route Name
GET         /photo                  index       photo.index
GET         /photo/create           create      photo.create
POST        /photo                  store       photo.store
GET         /photo/{photo}          show        photo.show
GET         /photo/{photo}/edit     edit        photo.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photo/{photo}          update      photo.update
DELETE      /photo/{photo}          destroy     photo.destroy


Adding Additional Routes To Resource Controllers

If it becomes necessary to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource:

Route::get('photos/popular', 'PhotoController@method');

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');

*/

// Display all SQL executed in Eloquent
// Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
// {
//     var_dump($query);
// });



define('ADMIN','admin');
define('SITE','site');


Route::group(['namespace' => ADMIN], function () {
    Route::get('/','UserController@showLogin'); 
});


////////////////////////////////////Routes for backend///////////////////////////////////////////////////
Route::group(['prefix' => ADMIN,'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['namespace' => ADMIN], function () {
    //Route::get('/','EshopController@products');

        //sumit routes for user registration
        //Route::resource('users','UserController');
        Route::get('/users/destroy/{id}','UserController@destroy');
        Route::get('UserProf','UserController@userProf');
        Route::get('users','UserController@index');
        Route::get('/users/create','UserController@create');
        Route::get('/users/adminEdit/{id}','UserController@adminEdit');
        Route::post('/users/adminUpdate','UserController@adminUpdate');
        Route::post('/users/store','UserController@store');
        Route::get('/users/edit/{id}','UserController@edit');
        Route::post('/users/update/{id}','UserController@update');

        //airlines route
        Route::get('airlines','AirlinesController@index');
        Route::get('/airlines/create','AirlinesController@create');
        Route::post('/airlines/store','AirlinesController@store');
        Route::get('/airlines/edit/{id}','AirlinesController@edit');
        Route::post('/airlines/update','AirlinesController@update');
        Route::get('/airlines/destroy/{id}','AirlinesController@destroy');
        //end sumit routes

        //flight routes
        Route::get('flights','FlightController@index');
        Route::get('showFlightBook','FlightController@showFlightBook');
        Route::get('flights/create','FlightController@create');
        Route::post('flights/store','FlightController@store');
        Route::get('flights/book','FlightController@book');
        Route::get('flights/edit/{id}','FlightController@edit');
        Route::post('flights/update','FlightController@update');
        Route::get('flights/destroy/{id}','FlightController@destroy');

        //Route::resource('flight','FlightController');

        //hotels route
        Route::get('hotels','HotelsController@index');
        Route::get('/hotels/create','HotelsController@create');
        Route::post('/hotels/store','HotelsController@store');
        Route::get('/hotels/edit/{id}','HotelsController@edit');
        Route::post('/hotels/update','HotelsController@update');
        Route::get('/hotels/destroy/{id}','HotelsController@destroy');
        //end sumit routes

        //book-hotel routes
        Route::get('hotel-book','HotelBookController@index');
        Route::get('showHotelBook','HotelBookController@showHotelBook');
        Route::get('hotel-book/create','HotelBookController@create');
        Route::post('hotel-book/store','HotelBookController@store');
        Route::get('hotel-book/book','HotelBookController@book');
        Route::get('hotel-book/edit/{id}','HotelBookController@edit');
        Route::post('hotel-book/update','HotelBookController@update');
        Route::get('hotel-book/destroy/{id}','HotelBookController@destroy');


        //Route::resource('hotel','HotelController');
        //close flight routes


        //for admin login
        //Route::get('initlogin','UserController@lgnPage');
        Route::get('login','UserController@showLogin');
        // Route::get('privilegeLogin','UserController@privilegeLogin');
        // Route::post('privilegeCheck','UserController@privilegeCheck');
        Route::post('login','UserController@doLogin');
        Route::get('/dashboard','DashController@index');
        Route::get('logout','UserController@doLogout');
        //user login 
        //Route::get('userLogin','UserController@showUserLogin');
        //Route::post('userLogin','UserController@doUserLogin');
        Route::get('/userDashboard','DashController@userIndex');
        Route::get('Logout','UserController@doUserLogout');
        //password reset
        Route::get('forget-pass','UserController@showReset');
        //Route::get('home', 'PassResetEmailController@index');






  });   
});

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Authenticate.php:

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate {

    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                // return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
                return redirect()->guest('/');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: This should be handled in the middleware file `Authienticate.php`. See the lines here: `{ ... } return redirect()->guest('auth/login');` What does your `routes.php` look like? Are all routes that require you to be logged in grouped by this middleware?

Comment: @TimLewis no it is not grouped,Ok if grouping route by this `Authenticate.php` middleware does the work,I will give it try.so on  `return redirect()->guest('auth/login');`  the redirect path should be replace with our own login page path is it?

Comment: @Sumit yes it should be your login page path

Comment: @TimLewis I don't know for what reason,the page always redirects back to login page whatever credentails I put on login page when I apply Authenticate.php middleware on routes.The user was able to login before I use this middleware.What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a middleware to be run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.
So, to protect every route from being accessed without authentication do this

```
protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',// add this line according to your namespace
    ];
```

it will redirect the user if not logged in. **UPDATE** Keep in mind that adding `auth` middleware as global will create redirect loop so avoid it.

Or if you want specific routes to be protected then attach the middleware `auth` to that route

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
```

I think you are not attaching the auth middleware to your routes.

Answer (score 11):

All you have to do is just put this constructor at the top of the controller for your dashboard. It seems Laravel has a middleware that handles this already. At least I can confirm from 5.4 and up.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Yes, you would put this constructor at the top of all Controllers where you use property data from the Auth class. Now what will happen is that when the session expires laravel will will ask the user to login, hence setting session data again then redirect to the page the using was sitting on when session expired.

Answer (score 9):

If the session expires then you can redirect  to log in like as
open this file app/Exceptions/Handler.php add this code

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {

            return redirect('/login');

        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: You're putting this under the "render" method of the Handler, correct?

Comment: Handler.php

  public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {

            return redirect('/login');

        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

Answer (score 5):

Create a middleware like this

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then Group the routes and protect them like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get();
    Route::get();
    Route::get();
    Route::get();
}
```

Offcourse, in the routes you have to specify your links etc, it will only allow the user when he is authenticated and if not then login page will be shown

Answer (score 2):

To make session redirect to your login just add `->middleware('auth')` in your router files as shown below I am using laravel 5.3

Ex:

```
Route::post('controllerName','folderName\fileName@fnNmae')->middleware('auth');
```

Or visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication