# Page expired instead of redirecting to login page after session timeout in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

After a specified session lifetime completion my application is redirecting to the login page on pressing any links, but if I submit any form by clicking the submit button it is showing the page is expired due to inactivity. I guess the redirection is working in case of get requests and is failing in case of post requests. Can someone help me in fixing this?

I have already tried

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    return $request->expectsJson() ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401) : redirect()->guest(route('login')); 
}
```

Comment: [Make session expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443632/make-session-expiration-redirect-back-to-login) check this answer.

Comment: @Vadim Kotov Are  you using any caching ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `csrf_field()` function in form to pass CSRF token to avoid `Page expired` error

```
<form action="" method="post">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

<!-- Your custom fields here -->
<input type="text" name="username" />
</form>
```