# How to fix 'trying to get property 'id' of non object. after logout when i go back then error i got

Tags: laravel

First of all thanks in advance.

When I log out of my admin panel and go back later (to make sure it does not go to the admin page without a login) I get an error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Here is My controller.php

```
protected $user_info;
protected $user_id;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $check_url = $request->segment(1);

        if($check_url == 'admin')
        { 
            $login_user_info = auth()->guard('admin')->user();

            $login_user_id = auth('admin')->user()->id;
            **// error here is**

            $login_user_role_id = auth('admin')->user()->role; 

            $this->user_info = Admin::with(['role_list'])
            ->where('id',$login_user_id)
            ->get()->toArray();
        }
        return $next($request);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) { 
    $check_url = $request->segment(1); 
    if($check_url == 'admin') {

        // check if admin is logged in
        If( !Auth::guard('admin')->check() ){
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        $login_user_info = auth()->guard('admin')->user();                
        $login_user_id = auth('admin')->user()->id;

        $login_user_role_id = auth('admin')->user()->role;
        $this->user_info = Admin::with(['role_list'])->where('id',$login_user_id) ->get()->toArray();
  }
  return $next($request); });
```

Because you were not checking if admin is still logged in, your code will attempt to retrieve the user id which is not set. I updated your code to include the check

Comment: @maulik savaliya did it fix your problem?

Comment: Verify the answer

Answer (score 0):

ok. sometimes when the user didn't have any action for a long time in laravel in the admin panel, so, the session expired.

then some variables in blade pages didn't have any value and this error happened.

so we need to have middleware for it to handle it and we should force the admin user to log off when the session expired.

like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680091/308578