# Laravel - Notification Message due to user inactivity

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

How will I add an error notification when user is inactive for 5 minutes? I'd like to put on my log in page

I have done minor configuration which helps me to track of user inactivity, I'd like to pass a message after the session is destroyed.

Just like this, But I dont know where should I put this. Thanks for any help and suggestion.

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with('inactivity', 'You're inactive for 5 minutes');
```

My session.php configuration I have made

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 5),

'expire_on_close' => true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's automatically available in Laravel after session expiry while using ['auth' middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443632/make-session-expiration-redirect-back-to-login).

You need to add a [middleware](https://arjunphp.com/laravel5-inactivity-idle-session-logout/) that will provide you with check for inactivity into your middleware stack and modify according to your algorithm of inactivity.

*Please note that message will be available **AFTER** user makes a request to your application.*

Comment: Is there any option I can do without using middle ware? thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: The middleware is there to avoid copy-pasting same code in many places. It's the easiest and most convenient method in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Daniel!